# Angular, remove HTML tags which are coming from database

Tags: javascript, angular

From database and webservices I am getting data in string form, which includes HTML tags

for HTML

```
{{data[0].summary}}
```

The page renders like that

```
someText<p>someText</p><h1>ldkel</h1><strong>some text</strong>
```

I dont want to show any tags into page
What I tried

`<span  [innerHTML]="data[0].summary"</span>` // didn't work for me

Also I tried by JavaScript
.ts

```
someVar = data[0].summary.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

.html

```
 {{someVar}}, [innerHTML] = "someVar"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Please read the question carefully I already used above method   <span = [innerHTML]="data[0].summary"</span>

Comment: You have to use the DOM sanitizer: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90

Comment: You already tried but with syntax errors in your markup. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gz9fp4).

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried this code and it *does* work:**
You may have syntax problems when it didn't work, try copy pasting the code below:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data[0].summary"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an error in your markup if innerHtml is not working.

You may try using the DOM sanitizer and see if that fixes your issue.

I made a small example for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16mprd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts